# Yii password repeat field

Tags: yii, passwords, confirmation

I want password repeat field in my web-application based on Yii when create and update user. When create I want both fields to be required and when update, user can left these fields empty(password will be the same) or enter new password and confirm it. How can I dot it?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/277/model-password-confirmation-field/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First up, you need to create a new attribute in your model (in this example we call it *repeatpassword*):

```
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord{
    public $repeatpassword;
    ...
```

Next, you need to define a rule to ensure it matches your existing password attribute :

```
    public function rules() {
            return array(
                array('password', 'length', 'max'=>250),
                array('repeatpassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>"Passwords don't match"),
                ...
            );
    }
```

Now, when a new model is created, the model will not validate unless the password and *repeatpassword* attributes match. As you mentioned, this is fine for **creating** a new record, but you don't want to validate the matched password on the **update**. To create this functionality, we can use [model scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/)

We simply change the *repeatpassword* rule as seen above to have an additional parmanter:

```
...
array('repeatpassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>"Passwords don't match",'on'=>'create'),
...
```

All that is left to do now, is when declaring your model on for the create function, use:

```
$model = new MyModel('create');
```

Instead of the normal:

```
$model = new MyModel;
```

Comment: One gotcha about your current setup is if the user is trying to update their password at a later date.  But other than that, looks good.

Comment: Well generally you would probably ask the user to input their password twice if they were updating. I did account for this with the scenario anyway ($model = new MyModel('create');)

Comment: You can use sceario name as update which is default each time Yii creates AR model. and so your model becomes `$model = new MyModel;`

Comment: See complete example here http://scriptbaker.com/yii-password-repeat-password-fields/

Comment: in my case the confirm password field value will also be inserted to database causing duplicate error. How to not include the confirm  password value to be submitted or to be saved in the database?

Comment: @goseo very similar- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979640/repeat-password-does-not-work-in-yii2