# Repeat Password does not work in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have written rules in the model as:

```
    public $password_repeat;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ....
        ....  
        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
        ['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>"Passwords don't match" ],
    ];
}
```

If I use different password in `Password` and `Password Repeat` field, it gives error. So, that's mean it works. But problem is that, it does not give any error if `Password Repeat` field is empty.

Comment: you need to mention required with repeat password like ['password_repeat', 'required'],

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add a required tag for password_repeat as well. Shown below

```
return [
        ....  
        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
        ['password_repeat', 'required'],
        ['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>"Passwords don't match" ],
    ];
```

Comment: We need not to use `required` in `Yii.1.*`. Can you tell me why we need to use in `Yii2`?

Comment: Yii  and Yii2 have a lot of undocumented differences due to yii2 being built independently from scratch. This is just one of them.

Answer (score 13):

Another approach is to set the $skipOnEmpty variable to false:

```
return [
....  
    ['password', 'required'],
    ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
    ['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'message'=>"Passwords don't match"],
];
```

This has the benefit of allowing you to only make the repeat password field required if password has a value in it too.

Comment: brilliant - thank you. For anybody else trying this, you need to add a public variable to the model otherwise the form will declare an error. I.e.: public $password_repeat